# Handle multiple forms behavior with a single javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 different HTML pages containing a form.
All forms look the same except their id attribute (and some children id attributes), though Javascript behavior should be same for every form.

I want to call a same Javascript function on some action but have to identify from which form the action has been triggered so the function knows which part of its body should be executed.

**form1.html**

```
<form id="form1">
 <input id="fname1"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btn-sub" onclick="fun()"/>
 <p id="demo"></p>
</form>
```

**form2.html**

```
 <form id="form2">
 <input id="fname2"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btn-sub" onclick="fun()"/>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 </form>
```

**form3.html**

```
 <form id="form3">
 <input id="fname3"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btn-sub" onclick="fun()"/>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 </form>
```

**javascript function**

```js
function fun() {
    // Here I would like conditions to look like
    if ( /* function call from form1 id then */ ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello form 1";
    }
    if ( /* function call from form2 id then */)  {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello form 2";
    }
    if ( /* function call from form3 id then */) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello form 3";
    }
 }
```

Comment: you can pass different parameters to fun() and based on that you can add conditions to the if...

Comment: how i can send current form id as a parameter to javascript function

Comment: Formatted, rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun()
     {

     var formID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
     //here i want conditions like
     if(formID==your Condition1)
     {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello form 1";
     }
     if(formID==your Condition2)
     {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello form 2";
     }
     if(formID==your Condition2)
     {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello form 3";
     }
     }
```

Comment: var formID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id"); its not working in y javascript function. can i use this in .js file in javascript function

Answer (score 0):

and you will remove **onclick** function from submit button.

you will use jquery event handler like this :-

```
$(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
            switch(event.target.id)
                 case 'form1':
                 // Do Some Code
                 break;

                 case 'form2':
                 // Do Some Code
                 break;                     
        });
    });
```